# Cannot create new project under organisation in azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I am login in as main account, is same account i used to create azure account. I have created organisation previously and have created project in azure DevOps but unable to do again. I in require organisation. I can see button `New Project` but when i click nothing happened. I am unable to create new project not sure why this happening

Comment: Check the F12 Developer Tools option from chrome to see if you get any error from the api

Comment: You can log in with the organization owner account from the **InPrivate window**, and then try to create a new project. If it doesn't work, check the F12 network trace as mentioned by @Jayendran. By the way, you can also try using [this REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP) to create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to create a new project in Azure DevOps under your organization despite being logged in with the main account, it could be due to a few potential issues:

1. **Browser Issues**: Sometimes, browser-related issues can cause buttons not to respond. Try clearing your browser cache, **using a different browser**, or incognito mode.
2. **Permissions**: Ensure that your account has the necessary permissions to create new projects in the organization. Even if you're the main account holder, it's worth checking the specific permissions in Azure DevOps. You must be a member of the `Project Collection Administrators group` or have the collection-level `"Create new projects" permission set to Allow.`
   [image]
3. **Service Outages**: Check if there are any ongoing service outages or maintenance activities in Azure DevOps that might be affecting project creation.
4. **Organization Settings**: Review your organization settings in Azure DevOps to ensure there aren't any restrictions or settings that might be preventing the creation of new projects.
   [image]

*By the way, if you have used an organization email to sign up for Azure DevOps, then your org needs to grant O365 access. I've signed up with my personal email and didn't run into this issue.*

In order to create a new project in Azure DevOps

click on `+ new project`
[image]

Give your project a name, description, choose the visibility
[image]

You can modify the project settings accordingly as per your requirement.
[image]

If the above suggested steps don't resolve the issue, consider reaching out to Azure support for more direct assistance. Azure DevOps has comprehensive documentation and support channels that can provide further guidance.

**Reference Document:**
[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/create-project?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)